# Does the Journal update for "fetch" missions?

Tags: mass-effect-3

*Mass Effect 3* has a wide array of "Fetch [X] from System [Y]" missions that can be obtained simply by listening to conversations overheard from people on the Citadel as you're walking past.

The problem with this is that the entries these missions make in your Journal are *incredibly* vague. For example:

> **Citadel: Improved Power Grid**
>   A technician at Purgatory on the Citadel needs an improved power grid to keep things running. Find schematics for a new power grid and deliver them.

Unfortunately you pick up a *lot* of random stuff when scanning the various systems in the galaxy (war assets, fuel, salvage, etc.).

**Is there any indication given via a Journal update to show when this (or any) mission item has been found?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the journal gives no indication whether you've completed the objective or not. If you have, you will be able to talk to the quest giver, otherwise you won't.

Comment: true. Real shitty, because with the amount of do-this-for-me missions, it becomes easy to lose track of what you've done & how far you've come along

Comment: That's the reason why I am following the Walkthrough of IGN concerning these objectives. Really annoying...